# \date{} doesn't work with new update

Tags: miktex, babel, date

When I use `\date{}` with the recent updates, see example below:

```
\begin{document}
\title{Mathematics of Finance 2}
\author{Daniel Royer\\
  Geneva Business School\\February 2018}
\date{February 2018}
\maketitle
```

I get:

```
 Paragraph ended before \FB@date was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

It worked perfectly before the update.
Any ideas?

Comment: I forgot to mention it's about Miktex!

Comment: Which TeX engine -- pdfTeX, XeTeX, or LuaTeX -- do you employ?

Comment: Please do not post such fragments of code only. We need a full document

Comment: Which documentclass?

Comment: I _think_ this is caused by `\usepackage[french]{babel}`: I'll raise with the maintainer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`babel-french` v3.4a introduces a new command `\frenchdate` requiring three numerical arguments (year,month, day) to format dates in French.

I thought cute to have `\date` redefined as `\frenchdate` in French but obviously it was a bad idea :-(

I'll correct this and release a 3.4b version asap.

Meanwhile a quick fix for your problem is to move command `\date{February 2018}` into the preamble.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand how it got moved.